# how to implement onclicklistener to a dynamically creating textview?

Tags: android, dynamic, onclicklistener

Currently i am having some problem with implementing onclicklistener to a dynamically creating textview. I will explain the problem more detailed. What i need to do is, i need to create textviews when i click a button in an activity and when i click on that textview it should get removed. but i am not able to set onclicklistener to each textview. Since, set onclicklistener of textviews are written inside the onclick function of the above said button(button used for creating the textview), its scope get over when it exits from onclick function of the button(i think this is the problem). So i tried using visible and invisible feature, which will create the textviews before hand and make them invisible and they are made visible only when the button(button used for creating the textview)is clicked. But here even though it is invisible the space will be allocated(ie, blank space will be availabe).

Here is my code
This button addphone will dynamically create textview by inserting the value present in the edittext phoneno

```
addphone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(phoneno.getText().toString().length() > 0 && counter < MAX)
            {
                addphoneno[counter] = phoneno.getText().toString();
                phoneno.setText("");
                final TextView mybox = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                mybox.setText(addphoneno[counter]);
                mybox.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                mybox.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(99, 99, 99));
                contactbox[counter] = mybox;
                contactbox[counter].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                contactbox[counter].setId(100+counter);
                contactbox[counter].setText(addphoneno[counter]+"  "+"X");

                contactbox[counter].setClickable(true);
                contactbox[counter].setOnClickListener(this);     //This doesn't work!!!!!
                counter = counter+1;
            }
    }
});
```

But the setOnClickListener in the above line is not working

So can anyone pls help me with this problem. I hope you are clear with my question.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
private OnClickListener phoneViewClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // your code
    }
};
```

and use that listener in your TextViews:

```
contactbox[counter].setOnClickListener(phoneViewClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to actually define a onClickListener instead of simply setting it as a boolean value.

```
contactbox[counter].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //this is where you would handle your click event
    }
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your button was defined on the xml layout you can do that.

In your xml layout you can define which method will be called when a user click on your button:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/add_phone"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/button_send"
     android:onClick="addTextView" />  // This is most imporant line
```

Your activity must have a method with the same name with a View parameter, like that:

```
/** Called when the user touches the button */
public void addTextView(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button click
    if(phoneno.getText().toString().length() > 0 && counter < MAX)
        {
            addphoneno[counter] = phoneno.getText().toString();
            phoneno.setText("");
            final TextView mybox = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            mybox.setText(addphoneno[counter]);
            mybox.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            mybox.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(99, 99, 99));
            contactbox[counter] = mybox;
            contactbox[counter].setLayoutParams(new   LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            contactbox[counter].setId(100+counter);
            contactbox[counter].setText(addphoneno[counter]+"  "+"X");

            contactbox[counter].setClickable(true);
            contactbox[counter].setOnClickListener(this);     //This will work \o/
            counter = counter+1;
        }
}
}
```

On this method you should put your code to addViews.

As the behavior of all added textview must to be the same( i understood in that way), be removed when a user clicked on it,  **you can make your activity implements onClickListener and with that you just need to implement correctly the onClick method  of your activity.**